How to use Angular Select
I want to select the data, which I previously designed as a different table in the backend section, with select and save it according to this selected operation. It seems logical to use angular material select for this, but I could not achieve this process myself.My goal here is to retrieve the water with a different table name using the select operation while adding a product to the product form. I am waiting for your help.
Water Type as a class:
export class List_Water_Type{

    id:string;
    waterType:string;
    conductance:number;
    conductanceMax:number;

}

create product as a class:
import { List_Water_Type } from "./water";
export class Create_Product {
    water?: List_Water_Type[];
}

create component ts:
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productValidation = this.formBuilder.group({
  weight:['', [Validators.required]],
      nitrogen: [false],
      water:[new FormControl()]
  });
  }

 @Output() createdProduct: EventEmitter<Create_Product> = new EventEmitter();

    create(){
      this.showSpinner(SpinnerType.BallAtom);
    const create_product: Create_Product = new Create_Product();
    this.productService.create(this.productValidation.value, () => {
      console.log(this.productValidation)
      if (this.data.callback) {
        this.data.callback();
      }
      this.hideSpinner(SpinnerType.BallAtom);
      this.alertify.message("Product successfully added.", {
        dismissOthers: true,
        messageType: MessageType.Success,
        position: Position.TopRight
      });
      this.createdProduct.emit(create_product); 
      console.log(create_product)

    }, errorMessage => {
      this.alertify.message(errorMessage,

        {
          dismissOthers: true,
          messageType: MessageType.Error,
          position: Position.TopRight
        });
    });

  }

Html:
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Water Type</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    @for () {
      <mat-option [value]=</mat-option>
    }
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>


Please add the relevant code (necessary to reproduce the problem) and remove the irrelevant code. For example, the create() function is completely unrelated to the issue, but the code to load the list from the backend is missing. Also you can check tutorials for the @for syntax and binding syntax.

There is no problem in the backend section. I tested it and it works. I just want to be able to use the variable named water coming from the backend by selecting it in the product form. Thank you for your comment.

You have to configure it as a formControlName. As for the syntax of @for. Please use the below working example as reference.
<form [formGroup]="productValidation">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Water</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="water">
      @for (listWaterType of listWaterTypes; track listWaterType) {
      <mat-option [value]="listWaterType.id"
        >{{listWaterType.waterType}}</mat-option
      >
      }
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>


loop through the array listWaterTypes for each object has the name listWaterType

We track this loop by using the entire object by track listWaterType, but you can also track it by a single ID track listWaterType.id (better), which improves performance.

we specify the id field as value for a option and label as waterType.


Stackblitz Demo
